# How to 'power clip' images into an object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been working with Corel Draw previously and now i use Illustrator more.Still getting used to some of their features though. I want to insert an image into a circle I've drawn but i don't know how to go about it.It is called power clipping in Corel. Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Adobe Illustrator we say it Clipping Mask which is Power Clip in Corel Draw. Below are steps to do it in Adobe Illustrator

1. Place your Image in Adobe Illustrator From File Menu
2. Draw Circle above the Image
3. Select Both Circle and Image
4. Pres <kbd>CTR + 7</kbd> For Clipping Mask

Clipping Mask command is given in last section of Object Menu in Adobe Illustrator Software